# ImportError: cannot import name 'disable_mlir_graph_optimization' from 'tensorflow.python.framework.config'

Tags: python, tensorflow

when import tensorflow i got
ImportError: cannot import name 'disable_mlir_graph_optimization' from 'tensorflow.python.framework.config'

tensorflow version == 2.12.1
python version == 3.9.1

from now tensorflow packages are well working but suddenly i got this error message and i could't solve this. please help me out

uninsall, reinstall tensorflow few times

Answer (score 0):

hi i appear to have the same problem.

i solve the problem by first uninstalling existing tensorflow library.
then open the installed packages directory,
for me its

C:\Users...\PythonCodingPack\Lib\site-packages

to check if there are still existing tensorflow packages, if there are any,
delete manually all folders associated with Tensorflow (more than 1 folder).

Then install tensorflow again and check if its installed properly.
Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).